# pandas how to convert two columns to groups list without duplicates

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have dataframe like the example:

```
a b
a c
b c
d e
```

How can I convert to list without duplicates by pandas or R:

```
a,b,c
d,e
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a network problem, so `networkx` is helpful:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(a,b) for a,b in zip(df[0],df[1])])

list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Output:

```
[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e'}]
```